# Can any one explain below python code ? I'am trying to store and update birthday data

Tags: python, python-3.x

program to store data about your friends’ birthdays. can you explain to me, friends stepwise or line `print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)`. how this recall `birthday[name]` to `birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}`. please help me to find out.

```
birthday = {'Alice': 'April 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}
while True:
    print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
    name = input()
    if name == ' ':
        break
    if name in birthday:
        print( birthday[name] + ' is birthday information of ' + name)
    else:
        print('I do not have birthday informtion for ' + name)
        print('What is their birthday?')
        bday = input()
        birthday[name] = bday
        print('Birthday database updated.')
```

Comment: if name in birthday:
        print( birthday[name] + ' is birthday information of ' + name) - I have doubt in this statement how it recall first statement, can you help me with example friends

Comment: it doesn't recall anything it's just accessing the elements in dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python dictionaries, when you subscript one like this: `birthday[name]`,

you are telling it to return the *value* for the *key* that was passed into the brackets.

So, `birthdays['Alice']` would give you `'Apr 1'`.